# R: fast method to check if integer value is in sorted integer vector and return its index

Tags: r, search, vector

Lets say I have **vector x** that:

- is very large ( > 200 000 )
- is integer
- is sorted
- all of it's values are unique

I would like to check if an **integer value y** is in this vector, and if it is, I would like to get the index of it. I would like to take advantage of the fact, that vector is sorted, so it can be done fast.

How would I accomplish such thing?

Comment: You mean `which(x == y)`?

Comment: would it stop looking for y, if it find value of x that is larger than y?

Comment: You can find an incident within an **unsorted**  1e8 (which is much larger than your vector) values vector within less than a second. I think you are wasting too much time thinking of it. Try `set.seed(123) ; x <- sample(1e8, replace = TRUE) ; system.time(res <- which.max(x == 1e7))`

Comment: David, your code freezed my machine... and returned elapsed time 110.097.

Comment: hmm, then you either have a very old machine or very old R version. It elapses in 0.75 for me. Either way, I gave an example for a much larger vector than you actually have. I'm sure `set.seed(123) ; x <- sample(2e5, replace = TRUE) ; system.time(which.max(x == 1e3))` will convert in not time (the real size of your vector).

Comment: Worked for me as well. Since we're talking speed, it seems that `which(x == 1e7)[1]` is still quite a bit faster (also for even larger vectors). @DavidArenburg do you happen to know why?

Comment: @Laterow you have a R core team member posted an answer below, you could ask him maybe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's some data

```
set.seed(123)
x = sort(unique(floor(runif(1e6, 1, 1e7))))
y = sample(1e7, 10000)
```

And a couple of approaches

```
f0 =  function(y, vec) y %in% vec
f1 = function(y, vec) vec[findInterval(y, vec)] == y
```

The `%in%` does a full scan; `findInterval()` does a binary search (I think). They generate the same result

```
> identical(f0(y, x), f1(y, x))
[1] TRUE
```

And have approximately similar amortized performance

```
> library(microbenchmark)
> microbenchmark(f0(y, x), f1(y, x), times=10)
Unit: milliseconds
     expr      min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
 f0(y, x) 99.35425 100.87319 102.32160 102.20107 103.67718 105.70854    10
 f1(y, x) 94.83219  95.05068  95.93625  95.77822  96.72601  97.50961    10
```

But `findInterval()` is I think faster for small queries

```
> microbenchmark(f0(y[1:10], x), f1(y[1:10], x), times=10)
Unit: milliseconds
           expr       min        lq      mean   median       uq       max neval
 f0(y[1:10], x) 83.441578 85.116818 86.264751 86.07515 87.13516 89.430801    10
 f1(y[1:10], x)  7.731606  7.734207  7.757201  7.75199  7.77210  7.810957    10
```

David suggests (I think)

```
f2 = function(x, vec) vec[which.max(x == vec)] == x
```

`which.max()` is only good for scalar `y`, which is seldom (saying this for the benefit of OP) a good use of R.  It appears less performant than `findInterval()`

```
> microbenchmark(f1(x[1000], x), f2(x[1000], x), times=10)
Unit: milliseconds
           expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 f1(x[1000], x) 7.707420 7.709047 7.714576 7.711979 7.718953 7.729688    10
 f2(x[1000], x) 9.353225 9.358874 9.381781 9.378680 9.400808 9.426102    10
```

Contrary to @Laterow I don't see any particular performance difference between `which()` and `which.max()` (in current R-devel or R-3-2-branch; also, the results aren't the same, so it's an apples-to-oranges comparison). I have a vague recollection of an R-devel conversation about this in the last 6 months...

```
> set.seed(123) ; x <- sample(2e5, replace = TRUE)
> microbenchmark(which.max(x == 1e7), which(x == 1e7)[1])
Unit: milliseconds
                  expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max
 which.max(x == 1e+07) 4.240606 4.266470 5.975966 5.015947 5.217903 43.78467
  which(x == 1e+07)[1] 4.060040 4.132667 5.550078 4.986287 5.059128 43.88074
 neval
   100
   100
```

Performance of `which` versus `which.max` might have changed with [this commit](https://github.com/wch/r-source/commit/c9042ad8cc1830c6e9dbb40c6929cf91b2c8bfd7#diff-6052e353fc7213f643fa5abbb0b07c46L818), where previously `which.max()` would coerce logical to numeric vectors before the scan, triggering a copy.

Comment: I think they are only checking for an integer value within a vector, rather a vector within a vector. Probably just `which` or `which.max` will dot he job very efficiently.

Comment: @MartinMorgan, I have a question. Using `which()[1]` seems to be faster than using `which.max` in this case. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @Laterow :  (regarding `which` vs `which.max`) What is your R version? It seems that only newer versions take advantage of "logical"s, while older coerce to "numeric" at front? If you use a benchmark like `x = sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 1e6, TRUE); numx = as.numeric(x); microbenchmark::microbenchmark(which.max(x), as.numeric(x), which.max(as.numeric(x)), which.max(numx))` does it seem to indicate "numeric" coercion in `which.max`?

Comment: @alexis_laz I'm using 3.2.2, and there does seem to be "numeric coercion". But in this case, we are already looking at a numeric vector, right? So that shouldn't matter, or..?

Comment: @Laterow I believe it was this commit https://github.com/wch/r-source/commit/c9042ad8cc1830c6e9dbb40c6929cf91b2c8bfd7 ; previously, the logical vector was coerced to numeric (original line 818), and then scanned for min / max value. Coercing to numeric would be costly.